# Debug Kotlin inline functions

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, inline

I´m using inline functions at my Kotlin-based Android project (I´m forced to, since I use reified key word). Is there a possibility to debug inline functions similar to regular ones? Breakpoints don´t snatch, which, I guess, has to do with the code insertion procedure of inline functions

Comment: Yep, IntelliJ and AndroidStudio do a bad job at setting breakpoints in Kotlin code - especially with inline functions and inlined lambdas

Comment: This is supposed to work normally. If it doesn't, please file a YouTrack issue with a specific example of the code where the breakponts do not work.